# Theme UI sx prop ignored when importing a storybook component

Tags: reactjs, theme-ui

I have setup and published to a private server a StoryBook design system using [ThemeUI](https://theme-ui.com/components/) that contains components. One such component is the button shown below.

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { Button as ButtonUI, SxStyleProp } from "theme-ui";

export const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({ onClick, children, variant, sx, disabled, onMouseOver, onMouseOut }) => {
    return (
        <ButtonUI
            disabled={disabled || false}
            variant={variant || "primary"}
            onClick={onClick}
            sx={{...sx}}
            onMouseOver={onMouseOver || (() => {})}
            onMouseOut={onMouseOut || (() => {})}
        >
            {children}
        </ButtonUI>
    );
};

export type ButtonProps = {
    /**
     * The action to perform when the button is clicked
     */
    onClick: () => void;
    /**
     * The contents of the button
     */
    children?: any;
    /**
     * The type of button
     */
    variant?: string;
    /**
     * custom styles for the button
     */
    sx?: SxStyleProp;
    /**
     * If the button is disabled
     */
    disabled?: boolean;
    /**
     * The action to perform if the mouse moves over the button
     */
    onMouseOver?: () => void;
    /**
     * The action to perform if the mouse moves off the button
     */
    onMouseOut?: () => void;
};

Button.defaultProps = {
    variant: "primary",
    disabled: false
};
```

When I import this component into my React App in a separate project the component renders but all properties in the sx prop are ignored...

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { Flex, jsx } from "theme-ui";
import Modal from "../Modal";
import { Button } from "<<<PRIVATE SERVER>>>";

/**
 * Renders a popup the gives the player the option to logout
 * @param title the heading of the modal
 * @param confirmString the text for the confirm button
 * @param cancelString the text for the cancel button
 * @param confirmAction the action to perform when the user confirms
 * @param cancelAction the action to perform when the user cancels
 */
export default function LogoutModal({ title, confirmString, cancelString, confirmAction, cancelAction }: Props) {

    return (
        <Modal
            title={title}
            closeAction={cancelAction}
            children={
                <Flex>
                    <Button
                        onClick={confirmAction}
                        sx={{
                            mr: 1
                        }}
                        variant="negative">{confirmString}</Button>
                    <Button
                        onClick={cancelAction}
                        sx={{
                            ml: 1
                        }}
                        variant="secondary">{cancelString}</Button>
                </Flex>
            }
        />
    );
}

interface Props {
    title: string;
    confirmString: string;
    cancelString: string;
    confirmAction: () => void;
    cancelAction: () => void;
}
```

So the button renders but without the applicable margin (or any other styles I add in the sx prop. Does anyone have any idea why this would be the case?

Interestingly if I call the component somewhere else in Storybook (rather than when imported into a seperate project) the sx prop works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR `sx` gets transformed to a `className` by theme-ui

See the [**working CodeSandbox demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/theme-ui-sx-prop-ktj4u?file=/src/App.jsx), then continue reading.

---

From the [documentation](https://theme-ui.com/sx-prop/):

> Under the hood, Theme UI uses a [custom pragma comment](https://theme-ui.com/guides/jsx-pragma/) that converts a
> theme-aware `sx` prop into a style object and passes it to Emotion's `jsx`
> functions. The `sx` prop only works in modules that have defined a
> custom pragma at the top of the file, which replaces the default React
> `jsx` functions. This means you can control which modules in your
> application opt into this feature without the need for a Babel plugin
> or additional configuration. This is intended as a complete
> replacement for the Emotion custom JSX pragma.

### Use the pragma on every file

So it's first needed to have the pragma comment at the top of the file, and import the right `jsx` function:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, Button as ButtonUI, SxStyleProp } from 'theme-ui';
```

The `sx` prop isn't passed down to the component, it's in fact converted to CSS and a `className` is auto-generated and applied to the component.

### Pass down the `className`

So if you'd like the parent component applying custom style to the `Button` component via the `sx` prop, you need to pass down the `className` prop.

```
export const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({
  onClick,
  children,
  variant,
  // This does nothing...
  // sx,
  disabled,
  onMouseOver,
  onMouseOut,
  // Make sure to pass the className down to the button.
  className, // or ...props
}) => (
  <ButtonUI
    className={className}
    // {...props} // if you want any other props
    sx={{ /* any other style can be applied here as well */ }}

    disabled={disabled || false}
    variant={variant || 'primary'}
    onClick={onClick}
    onMouseOver={onMouseOver || (() => {})}
    onMouseOut={onMouseOut || (() => {})}
  >
    {children}
  </ButtonUI>
);
```

---

Personal recommendation is to **not** use some kind of hack passing down `sx` content down. I've been working on a huge project professionally that uses theme-ui and never have we ever needed anything else than pass the `className` down to merge styles automatically.

Comment: I am going to give this a whirl in a test project. If it works I think this is more of an elegant solution.

Comment: @alasdair009 I've added a working demo to prove my point.

Comment: The pragma for the new theme-ui version is : /** @jsxImportSource theme-ui */,

Thanks, EmileBergeron for providing me conceptual clarity on how theme-ui works under the hood :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so turns out if you need to change the name of the property passed into the component or themeui appears to get confused. So I made the following change (changed sx to csx):

```
export const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({ onClick, children, variant, csx, disabled, onMouseOver, onMouseOut }) => {
    return (
        <ButtonUI
            disabled={disabled || false}
            variant={variant || "primary"}
            onClick={onClick}
            sx={{...csx}}
            onMouseOver={onMouseOver || (() => {})}
            onMouseOut={onMouseOut || (() => {})}
        >
            {children}
        </ButtonUI>
    );
};
```

Then when the component is called you use the csx instead of sx.